# Copy rows from multiple Sheets into one, then order by column

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a single VBA that searches seven different sheets for a particular entry in Column E and then copy the entire row into a 8th Sheet and placing them in order by column A.

I got the point for it to search for one spreadsheet and copying the items over to the other in the exact same row they are located on the spreadsheet

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rw As Long, Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Tues.Range("E:E")
    rw = Cell.Row
     If Cell.Value = "No" Then
      Cell.EntireRow.Copy
       Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & rw).PasteSpecial
     End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The Spreadsheets I want to search for are:
   Mon
   Tues
   Wed
   Thurs
   Fri
   Sat
   Sun

The sheet I want to move it to is called `Completed`, then I want it to sort by Column A.

Any Ideas?

Comment: A quick note - it's not recommended to use a variable with the name `Cell` since `Cell` means something specific to VB.  I like to use `cel` instead.  Also, you're searching *each and every* cell in the entire Column E for "No"?  That's going to take a while.  Is that absolutely necessary, or can we look instead for a last row?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Sub loop_through_WS()
Dim rw As Long, i As Long, lastRow As Long, compLastRow&
Dim cel     As Range
Dim mainWS As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetArray() As Variant

sheetArray() = Array("Mon", "Tues", "Weds", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")

Set mainWS = Sheets("Completed")

compLastRow = mainWS.Cells(mainWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For i = LBound(sheetArray) To UBound(sheetArray)
    With Sheets(sheetArray(i))
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row
        For Each cel In .Range("E1:E" & lastRow)
            rw = cel.row
            If cel.Value = "No" Then
                cel.EntireRow.copy
                mainWS.Range("A" & compLastRow).pasteSpecial
                compLastRow = mainWS.Cells(mainWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

It basically uses the code you gave, but I added the worksheet loop (it'll loop through each of the day worksheets) and paste back onto the "Completed" WS.

See if you can work out how I looped through the worksheets - I use this type of thing often so it'd be good to learn if you are doing much of this.  It also allows you to add another sheet (say "Weekend") to your workbook and all you have to do is add "Weekend" after "Sun" in the Array.  That's the only place you'll need to add it.

One note is that I changed your `for each Cell in Range(E:E)` to be from `E1` to the last Row in column E - which makes the macro run way faster.

Edit: As mentioned in my comment above, it's generally not recommended to use `Cell` as a variable name. (Same goes for `Column`, `Row`, `Range`, etc.) because these all mean something specifically to VBA (i.e. `Cell([row],[column])`.  Instead, as you see, I like to use `cel` or `rng` or `iCell`,etc.

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of the code. It'd be even better if it filtered on "No" in column E and copied the visible cells into the Completed sheet. Much faster that way! No looping at all necessary. Imagine if column E had 500,000 rows!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - admittedly, I'm pretty new to the Filtering, but I agree - that would be a little better.  I'll see if I can feather that in, but the code I have now should work for OP, unless they have lots and lots of rows, in which case Filtering would certainly be better.  OP - will you be using this over say, 10,000 rows per sheet?

Comment: I can see this working as it is intended, however the pasting is still a bit weird as its pasting the rows in the exact location they are in the original sheet.

Example:  If it finds a Result in Tues, pastes it into completed and finds a Result on Fri it will paste over those cells.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Aidage - I updated the macro.  Now it will add the rows to the "Completed" sheet in the next "available" row.  (`compLastRow`).  Note that I'm assuming if there's data, column A will have data. (If all your data is going to be in column E, then change `...mainWS.Rows.Count,1)` to `...mainWS.Rows.Count,5)`.)

Comment: Do you know what would cause for the Macro to only run when the sheet is completely empty? Also to check for duplicates?  Not to worried about the duplicates

Comment: Just an FYI there is some sort of flaw going on that im trying to figure out.  The VBA is looking for the last row with an entry in it, then erases that row and starts from there,  Just an FYI

Comment: @Aidage - I'll look in to that.  Does it only do it one time? Change the first `compLastRow = ...` to include ` + 1` at the end too. That might fix it.  Also, I updated the code, replace and update with this line: `lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row` (I originally forgot the `.` before `Cells`).

Comment: It didn't work.  Its still erasing the first row that has a value.  Think its possible to tell it to copy the rows to completed from A7 onward?

Comment: Quick clarification - "Its still erasing the first row that has a value".  Do you mean that in your "Completed" worksheet, the first row keeps being overwritten?  It'll take the row with "No" from the other sheet, but just overwrites the same row again and again?

Comment: Lets say I have Items in A1:A5 and A7, the Macro will erase what is in A7 making it the first row it makes changes to rather than A8 (First Empty Row).  It will then populate the information all the way to A:$ depending on how many entries it fines.

Comment: @Aidage - sure, just add this line where you want that to occur: `Sheets("SheetName").Delete`.  Note that this will prompt the user and ask if they want to delete the sheet.  If you *don't* want this prompt, just add this before the `.delete` line: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and this after the `.delete` line: `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you based on what you've described. It uses a For Each loop to iterate through the sheets and uses the AutoFilter method to find what it's looking for from column E.  The code assumes headers are in row 1 on each sheet.  I attempted to comment it for clarity.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsCompleted As Worksheet
    Dim bHeaders As Boolean

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsCompleted = wb.Sheets("Completed")
    bHeaders = False

    'Comment out or delete the following line if you do not want to clear current contents of the Completed sheet
    wsCompleted.Range("A2", wsCompleted.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).Clear

    'Begin loop through your sheets
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        'Only perform operation if sheet is a day of the week
        If InStr(1, " Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun ", " " & Left(ws.Name, 3) & " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            'If headers haven't been brought in to wsCompleted yet, copy over headers
            If bHeaders = False Then
                ws.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy wsCompleted.Range("A1")
                bHeaders = True
            End If

            'Filter on column E for the word "No" and copy over all rows
            With ws.Range("E1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
                .AutoFilter 1, "no"
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Copy wsCompleted.Cells(wsCompleted.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .AutoFilter
            End With

        End If
    Next ws

    'Sort wsCompleted by column A
    wsCompleted.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort wsCompleted.Range("A1"), xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Here is the sample workbook that contains the code.  When I run the code, it works as intended.  Is your workbook data setup drastically different?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-nM5djZBWYaFV3WnprRC1GMnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is this line `.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Copy  ...` going to do what you intend? Is it only going to copy the filtered (visible) cells or all the cells in the range?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes, that will only copy visible cells in the range.

Comment: This function errors out for me or does not copy anything at all besides making about 60000 Columns.

Comment: @Aidage It ran successfully as intended for me when I tested it with sample data.  I'd have to see if you edited the code at all, or what your actual data is if it is not working for you.

Comment: @Aidage Edited post to include the sample workbook I tested it on.

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted earlier have some great stuff in them, but I think this will get you exactly what you after with no issues and also with great speed. I made some assumptions on how your data is laid out, but commented them. Let me know how it goes.

```
Sub PasteNos()

    Dim wsComp As Worksheet
    Dim vSheets() As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    vSheets() = Array("Mon", "Tues", "Weds", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")

    Set wsComp = Sheets("Completed")

    For i = LBound(vSheets) To UBound(vSheets)

        With Sheets(vSheets(i))

            .AutoFilterMode = False

            .Range(.Range("E1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).AutoFiler 1, "No"
            'assumes row 1 has headers
            .Range(.Range("E2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy

            'pastes into next available row
            With wsComp
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'assumes copy values over
            End With

        End With

    Next i

    'assumes ascending order, headers in row 1, and that data is row-by-row with no blank rows
    wsComp.UsedRange.Sort 1, xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```